# c# yolov5 with opencv (Error code: OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException: 'separator_index < line.size()')

Tags: c#, yolo

I trained a custom model using Colab. yolov5x.yaml and best.pt
An error occurs in the ReadNetFromDarknet function. I don't know why.
And i attach the contents of yolov5x.yaml as an image.

````
    ```  // path
     string modelCfg = "C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\Trade_detection\\Trade_detection\\bin\\Debug\\yolov5x.yaml";
     string modelWeights = "C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\Trade_detection\\Trade_detection\\bin\\Debug\\best.pt";
    
     // image path
     string imageFile = "test1.jpg";
    
     // yolo model load
     Net net = CvDnn.ReadNetFromDarknet(modelCfg, modelWeights);```
````

[image]

Comment: Can you add exception on `ReadNetFromDarknet` and post your error message here?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan this is my error Error code: OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException: 'separator_index < line.size()' i already convert to .onnx file